# Angular2 - detect component child variable change

Tags: angular, components, code-injection

Parent component

```
import { Component, OnChange } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from '../../reusable/user-offers/user-offers.component';
@Component({
  ...
  directives: [ ChildComponent ]
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnChange {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent)
    private child: ChildComponent;

  ngOnChanges() {
    detecting this.child.detectme variable...
  }

}
```

Child component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ParentComponent {    
  @Input() detectme: string;
  //in view something changes detectme value (not important here)
}
```

How can I detect if child.detectme changed and print it's value?

Comment: It is `ngOnChanges` not `ngOnChange`

Comment: Sorry, but that was caused by manually rewriting. I have ngOnChanges.

Answer (score 2):

You want to detect in parent component that the value in the child component changed, right? If so, you should use `EventEmitter` in the child component and emit the event. Then you subscribe to the event in the parent component using `(eventNameFromChild)="handler($event)"` syntax.

Created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KQVFoi5ZwYbCt2hjfcQO?p=preview) for you.